# Run Android Broadcast receiver while app only foreground

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast, android-background

My App is monitoring the network connection changes to decode offline and online cases. Here I want to continuously monitor this only when the app is in the foreground. How we can implement this using a BroadcastReceiver.
I am using the below code to run in the background. But it's also working once the app is closed or running in the background.

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        boolean mIsConnected = false;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();



        if (activeNetwork != null) {
          
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
              
                mIsConnected = true;
            } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
               
                mIsConnected = true;
            }
        }
        if (mIsConnected) {

            Log.d("mIsConnected11",mIsConnected+"");
        }
        else {

            Log.d("mIsConnected11",mIsConnected+"");

        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what is the min sdk version you target?

Comment: if your minSdk is 21 or above then, switch to `ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback`, it works like a charm

Comment: @rahat Min 26 and up to 30. Sure I will change that. But my problem is with the background running receiver. How to stop while closing the app.

Comment: i don't know if that will work or not, but try to use a service that work only in foreground and at commend you can start your receiver .

Answer (score 0):

`ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback` works like a charm for me, it immediately notifies me when I turn off the internet or disconnect from wifi and when connect back.

Then I would suggest using this in your application class, then you can register for the local broadcast receiver in your base activity.

```
    private ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback callback;
    
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        this.initNetworkMonitor();
    }

    void initNetworkMonitor(){
            this.callback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
                    super.onAvailable(network);
                    Log.d("UE_MONITOR","onAvailable");
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Constants.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGE);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGE, NetworkState.AVAILABLE);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(AppController.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onLosing(@NonNull Network network, int maxMsToLive) {
                    super.onLosing(network, maxMsToLive);
                    Log.d("UE_MONITOR","onLosing");
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Constants.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGE);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGE,NetworkState.LOSING);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(AppController.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onLost(@NonNull Network network) {
                    super.onLost(network);
                    Log.d("UE_MONITOR","onLost");
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Constants.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGE);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGE, NetworkState.LOST);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(AppController.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onUnavailable() {
                    super.onUnavailable();
                    Log.d("UE_MONITOR","onUnavailable");
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Constants.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGE);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGE, NetworkState.UNAVAILABLE);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(AppController.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            };
            ConnectivityManager manager=((ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
            manager.registerNetworkCallback(new NetworkRequest.Builder().build(),callback);
        }
```

`NetworkState` is an enum, you can make your as per your preference.